# Add widget in custom product taxonomies

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, custom-taxonomy

I am having hard time how to have a widget in custom taxonomies
This is my custom taxonomy (**gender**)

[image]

and I want to add widget like this same with product categories
[image]

I've tried in dashboard -> appearance -> customize

but there is no custom taxonomy to add widgets

[image]

---

**EDIT 1:**

I copy `index.php` from `matfury parent` then rename it to `taxonomy-gender.php` and this is the inside code, but still not works.
[image]

---

**EDIT 2**

I followed this steps [here](http://docs.drfuri.com/martfury/09-custom-category-sidebar/), but only missing is on my `Dashboard -> Products -> Gender`,
there is no custom sidebar option.
[image]

---

**Edit 3**
I installed plugin "Widget LogiC" and tried with these but no luck, it still not showing.

[image]

```
is_tax('')
is_tax('Gender')
is_tax('gender')
is_tax('Gender','gender')
is_tax('gender','female')
```

Answer (score 0):

Found that you are using **martfury** the premium theme. You can also go for the support forum with your valid purchase code.

Seems that you may have changed the code in taxonomy page. You need to include the

```
<?php get_sidebar(); ?>
```

to get the sidebar into the specific page.

Comment: on what file do I add this?

Comment: File may be the taxonomy-{taxonomy}-{term}.php get help from https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/taxonomy-templates/. Assuming  taxonomy-pa_gender.php

Comment: I copy index.php from matfury parent theme then rename it to `taxonomy-gender.php` and add sidebar, it still not works

Comment: Seems your taxonomy name is not geneder it may pa_gender. Please check once, if it is please change the taxonomy file name accordingly.